# Fixing errors in citations using biblatex

Tags: biblatex, texshop

I'm trying out `biblatex` which so far seems wonderful when it works. The process creates a plethora of files, and when I make a mistake (e.g. referring to a bibliographical entry incorrectly), I get to a point where I can't run either LaTeX or biber without an error. The only way I can figure out to get out of this mess is to remove the `.bbl` file.

Some details:

- I'm using biblatex v1.1 and biber 0.7.2.
- the error I get in latex is "Undefined control sequence...`\missing {referencex}` and then it seems that the `.bcf` file is incomplete
- I'm running LaTeX with whatever the defaults in TeXShop are, and using biber from the command line

Some questions:

- Is this the correct workflow?
- Is there an easier way to have it automatically deal with errors or do I manually have to remove these files when things get messed up?
- Can I get texshop to remove `.bbl` files using the trash `.aux` files menu command?

Comment: what happens when you force the compilation when dealing with an error message? you force a compilation with the letter "r" at the prompt.

Comment: ahh, that takes care of the second and third questions; if you want to write up a quick answer that also touches on the first question, I'd be happy to consider that as an answer to the question

Answer (score 5):

The remove `aux` files functionality of TeXShop is configurable through the command line `defaults` command: (from the TeXShop help panel:)

> When documents are typeset, auxiliary
>   files are created with extensions
>   .aux, .log, .bbl, etc. Occasionally
>   these files can become corrupt and
>   lead to unexplained typesetting
>   errors. TeXShop has a menu command
>   "Trash AUX Files" which will remove
>   all such files so typesetting can
>   proceed. There is a similarly named
>   button on the Console window. If
>   either of these items is activated,
>   TeXShop will move to the trash all
>   files in the current source directory
>   with the same name as the source file
>   and extension aux, blg, brf, ccs, ent,
>   fff, glo, idx, idv, ilg, ind, ioa, lg,
>   log, lot, mte, mlf, out, pdfsync, toc,
>   ttt, wrm, xref, 4ct, 4tc, or
>   fdb_latexmk.
>
> Additional extensions can be added to
>   this list. To add "dvi" to the list,
>   activate the Terminal and type
>
> defaults write TeXShop
>   OtherTrashExtensions -array-add "dvi"

So to get TeXShop to remove `biblatex` created files, you'll need to add any of the extra files that it creates to the removal list.

e.g.

```
defaults write TeXShop OtherTrashExtensions -array-add "bbl"
defaults write TeXShop OtherTrashExtensions -array-add "xml"
```

`biblatex` also creates a `-blx.bib` file.  Do *not* add `.bib` to the trash list, however, since that might delete your actual bibligraphy file, if it were in the same folder as your document.  I don't think it's possible to add `-blx.bib` to the list of trashable files.